# How to fetch weather data from internet using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, weather

You can find examples of code on how to fetch weather data using PHP, Ruby, Python, ColdFusion, and jQuery here: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples, I was wondering if there was an equivalent of this regarding VBScript that someone was aware of.

I have a very limited understanding of VB, no less VBS, but I found this code online which seems like it might work:

```
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next

Dim objXML, strXMLFile, weatherFor, weatherCondition, currTemp, highTemp, lowTemp

strXMLFile = "C:\Temp\test.xml"

Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async = "False"
objXML.load(strXMLFile)

weatherFor = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:location").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("city").value
weatherCondition = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("text").value
currTemp = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("temp").value
highTemp = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("high").value
lowTemp = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("low").value

WScript.Echo weatherFor
WScript.Echo weatherCondition
WScript.Echo currTemp
WScript.Echo highTemp
WScript.Echo lowTemp
```

But when I try to execute it I get the error: `Object required: getElementsByTagName(...).item(...)`

I've looked it up and this is the problem: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A01A8.htm, but I'm not sure what to make of it.

Does someone know how to solve this error code, or a better way to do this altogether? Thank you very much in advance.

[Edit:]

Here's some working code:

```
Dim WeatherRSS
WeatherRSS = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=CAXX0773&u=c"

Dim WinHttpReq, XMLData, objXML, weatherCity, weatherCondition, currTemp, highTemp, lowTemp
Dim Response, Talker

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

WinHttpReq.Open "GET", WeatherRSS, False
WinHttpReq.Send

If (WinHttpReq.Status = 200) Then
    XMLData = WinHttpReq.ResponseText

    Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXML.async = "False"
    objXML.loadXML(XMLData)

    weatherCity      = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:location").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("city").value
    weatherCondition = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("text").value
    currTemp         = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("temp").value
    highTemp         = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("high").value
    lowTemp          = objXML.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast").item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("low").value

    weather = weatherCondition & " " & currTemp & " " & highTemp & " " & 

lowTemp & " " + weatherCity & "."
else        weather = "Sorry, I can't predict the weather today."
end if

msgbox(weather)
```

Comment: What is the contents of `test.xml` ?

Comment: Also this seems like VBScript code. What does it have to do with VBA?

Comment: The code won't execute so I don't think the file even gets made. Ultimately, I'm trying to automate putting the date into an excel file as well as merge some other data from various excel files.

Comment: the `Load` method takes an XML from a *file* location. Do you *have* the XML on your local machine? If not, you would need to use `LoadXML` method to load a string, which could be pulled from an `XMLHTTPRequest`'s `.responseText`...

Comment: Also, please clarify whether this is "vbscript" or VBA...

Comment: You could try using `"Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0"` instead of `"Microsoft.XMLDOM"` but in this code you are retrieving, not setting values. and you appear to be passing the property of a JSON object to `getElementsByTagName` which will never work

Comment: I removed the `VBA` tag because you're right, this component is just the script. I got it to work, I'll post the working code in the question body now.

Comment: The reason the working code works is that it sends an HTTP request to the web weather API (rather than reading the file off disk). However, we still don't know what `WeatherRSS` returns. If its XML, fine, you can use `loadXML` to load it, but from the link you posted the web API appears to return JSON and not XML

Comment: Also you can use `Set objXML = WinHttpReq.ResponseXML` with `Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`, it's easier.